# convertir una fecha que retorna en un formato 2021-10-16T00:00:00

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estimada Red, tengo el problema en donde actualmente esto obteniendo los datos de una api previamente construida.

El problema es la fecha que se obtiene se muestra formato 2021-10-16T00:00:00 y quiero que se visualice como 2021-10-16 pero su origen es de tipo Date.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
const peticionPut=async()=>{
    await axios.post(baseUrl+"/"+reservaSeleccionada.ID, reservaSeleccionada)
    .then(response=>{
      var dataNueva=data;
      dataNueva.map(reservar=>{
          if(reservar.ID === reservaSeleccionada.ID){
            reservar.CODIGO = reservaSeleccionada.CODIGO;
            reservar.USUARIOID = reservaSeleccionada.USUARIOID;
            reservar.MESAID = reservaSeleccionada.MESAID;
            reservar.FECHA = reservaSeleccionada.FECHA;
            reservar.COMENSALES = reservaSeleccionada.COMENSALES;
            reservar.ESTADO = reservaSeleccionada.ESTADO;

          }
      });
      setData(dataNueva);
      abrirCerrarModalEditar();
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿Cuál es el formato que esperas o que buscas? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y agrega esos detalles.

Comment: El formato dado es el [estándar ISO](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Busco obtener el formato 2021/10/16

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato almacenas en `reservar.FECHA`? porque si es un tipo `string` basta con hacer el `substring` adecuado, en cambio si es un tipo `Date` pues con hacer uso del método `toISOString()` y luego con encadenar un `substring` lo tendrías.

Answer (score 6):

Para mostrar la fecha en el formato que especificas (`2021/10/16`), usa el método del objeto date `toLocaleDateString` pasándole como parámetro el formato que requieres, en este caso `'zh-Hans-CN'`.

```js
let date =new Date("2021-10-16T00:00:00")
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('zh-Hans-CN'));
```

Para especificar que requieres los meses y los días siempre con dos dígitos, puedes pasar de manera opcional como segundo parámetro el objeto:

```
{ year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' }
```

Answer (score 0):

tambien puedes hacerlo del lado de html

**Mi cumpleaños es: {{cumpleanos}}| date: "YY/mm/dd"**

donde "cumpleanos" es la variable que estas llamando desde js y "date" especificas el formato que quieres darle