# Fecha aparece en formato 2021-10-16T00:00:00

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estimada Red,

Tengo problemas con la fecha que se muestra en mi tabla, me entrega un formato 2021-10-16T00:00:00, y yo necesito un formato 16/10/2021.

Intente realizar una modificación en mi código con el toLocaleDateString('zh-Hans-CN') pero me sigue arrojando el mismo resultado :

```
 const peticionPut=async()=>{
    await axios.post(baseUrl+"/"+reservaSeleccionada.ID, reservaSeleccionada)
    .then(response=>{
      var dataNueva=data;
      dataNueva.map(reservar=>{
          if(reservar.ID === reservaSeleccionada.ID){
            reservar.CODIGO = reservaSeleccionada.CODIGO;
            reservar.USUARIOID = reservaSeleccionada.USUARIOID;
            reservar.MESAID = reservaSeleccionada.MESAID;
            reservar.FECHA = new Date.reservaSeleccionada.FECHA.toLocaleDateString('zh-Hans-CN');
            reservar.COMENSALES = reservaSeleccionada.COMENSALES;
            reservar.ESTADO = reservaSeleccionada.ESTADO;

          }
      });
      setData(dataNueva);
      abrirCerrarModalEditar();
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
    })
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese *locale* que estás utilizando [parece estar obsoleto](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-tags/language-tags.xml)

Comment: Conoces algún locale que este en funcionamiento?

Comment: @Arriel lo que está absoleto es la especificación no el locale.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [convertir una fecha que retorna en un formato 2021-10-16T00:00:00](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/491822/convertir-una-fecha-que-retorna-en-un-formato-2021-10-16t000000)

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, Gracias por la aclaración

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez No me funciono, por eso volví a subir la pregunta

Comment: @NicolasAlejandroTennettTapi ¿podrías adjuntar el fragmento de tu vista encargado de mostrar la fecha? Puede que el problema esté por ahí

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez ahí subí una imagen en mi pregunta del panorama actual

Comment: @NicolasAlejandroTennettTapi me referia al fragmento codigo html que contiene la tabla dentro del componente.

Answer (score -1):

Si tu salida es en `html` donde llamas la variable puedes hacer algo así:

```
<p>The hero's birthday is {{ birthday | date:"MM/dd/yy" }} </p>
```

`birthday` es la variable con el formato y `date` es el formato que quieres darle.